# Android activity to a fragment control transfer

Tags: android

I am creating an android application with three tabs using [PageSlidingtabStrip](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip) as a library to create a swipe view.And it has three fragments.Each fragments has a list view.When the item of the listview is clicked it opens an activity and display the details.

The problem is how can i come back to the fragment in the main screen using back button in actionbar in the activity

And how can i go to the corresponding Fragment(Tab)

Comment: It should already work, because the new activity is added to the back stack...

Comment: by pressing the back button on device.It's that simple unless you have override the obBackPressed.

Comment: Sorry here i am mentioning actionbar's back button not device back button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this :

```
   @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onBackPressed();
   Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentClass.this , ClassThatYouWantToGo.class);
   startActivity(intent)
}
```

Or actually like @TommyTopas said, you can just Override `onBackPressed` and put `this.finish();`.

**EDIT**

As I've understood you want to use a button on your AcitonBar, then you have tod o something like this : 
First set the HomeButton enabled doing :

`getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` Then Override `onOptionsItemSelected`

```
    @Override
            public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                    case android.R.id.home:

                     // or onBackPressed();
                     this.finish()

                    }
                    return true;
            }
```

Comment: here you are launching a new activity when the user press the back button... it's horrible

Comment: there's no need to override `onBackPressed `! by default it will close the activity

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, when you return to the "Tab" `Activity`, you want to display the same tab in which the list item had been clicked. What you can do is, when a list item in any tab is clicked, save the tab number in `onSavedInstanceState()`, and when the `Activity` is recreated, then set the previously selected tab (if one was selected previously). You will get the `savedInstanceState` that you saved in `onSavedInstanceState()` back in the `onCreate()` of the same `Activity`.

Comment: could you please give me sample for doing this

Comment: Basically you need to learn to save the instance state of `Activity` and `Fragment` ... there are any number of tutorials for this, see [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-1/) and [here](http://www.intertech.com/Blog/saving-and-retrieving-android-instance-state-part-2/).

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an [Up navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html) by writing `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);` and then in the `onOptionsItemSelected` method in the activity, if the item's id is `android.R.id.home` call the activity's method `onBackPressed();` which will close your current activity and come back to your fragment